# Projectile question doubt

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

A hunter wants to shoot a monkey with an arrow by launching the arrow at a speed $v_0$ at a distance of $L$ from the base of a tree of height $H$ on which the monkey is sitting. Now on watching the arrow being launched the monkey falls down with zero initial velocity from the tree. What should be the minimum value of $v_0$ in order to hit the monkey while its in air.

I tried to solve the problem using vector notation.
We can write the coordinate of the arrow at any time $t$ as

$$\vec{A} = (v_0cos\theta \hat{i} + v_0sin\theta \hat j )t - 1/2(gt^2)\hat{j}$$

taking the same directions together we would get.

$$\vec{A}=(v_0cos\theta t)\hat{i} + (v_0sin\theta t- 1/2(gt^2))\hat{j}$$

I can write the equation of motion in vector form for the monkey:

Let $\vec M$ be monkey's position vector

$$\vec M=L \hat i +(H -1/2((gt^2)\hat{j}$$

Now as the shot has to hit monkey, (lets say at time $t_0$) then at time $t_0$, $\vec M= \vec{A}$

Therefore 
$$v_0cos\theta t= L \tag1$$

$$v_0sin\theta t- 1/2(gt^2)=(H -1/2(gt^2))\tag2$$
$$\rightarrow v_0sin\theta t=H\tag3$$
Squaring and adding (1) and (3) we can easily get

$$v_o^2t^2=H^2+L^2$$

$$v_0=\sqrt{\frac{H^2+L^2}{t}}$$

Now how can I deduce any expression for time in order to substitute $t$?
I know that $\frac{dv_0}{d\theta}=0$ for the minimum but I am unable to find any expression in order to make up this expression.

Comment: your final expression says that v0 decreases as time increases.  I'd look for the longest time solution, ie, when the monkey is at the end of his fall.  It is illegal to shoot monkeys with arrows in most parts of the world.

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird   Sure.

Comment: @ACuriousMind     Why the topic has been put on hold.  I have truly shown my effort regarding the question and just asked over the last part i.e the time regarding the minimum velocity?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but SE physics has a somewhat restrictive policy regarding homework-like questions.  Sometimes "textbook like" questions get put on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should be the minimum value of $v_0$ in order to hit the monkey while it's in air?

Minimum value for $v_0$ is when arrow hits to the monkey **just before** it (monkey) reaches to the ground. Or, minimum value for $v_0$ is when arrow's range is equal to horizontal distance between hunter and monkey. So you need to find the time of monkey's fall. Or, you should substitute horizontal distance between hunter and monkey as arrow's range.